# Launch images for universal application

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode5

I am trying to set default launch images from general setting section for my project using xcode 5.
Issue is when I am trying to set launch images for ios 6.1 and prior retina of iPhone and iPad, xcode is forcing me to rename the file name from Default~ipad@2x.png to Default.png and Default~iphone@2x.png to Default.png for iphone. But if both the files having same name get loaded then it is not showing proper launch images as per device type.
Can anyone guide me for the same? I have attached screenshot of error for more information.[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Set the names to Default@2x~ipad.png and Default@2x~iphone.png

Comment: It worked thanks. But as per standards the previous naming convention was right. Then how is it forcing to rename it?

Comment: <basename>-<url_scheme><scale_modifier><device_modifier>.png where as scale_modifier @2x and device_modifier ~ipad. See the section "Providing Launch Images for Custom URL Schemes" in iOS App Programming Guide.